# How can I repair a 1/2" hole partially into one of the king studs of my bathroom door frame?

Tags: framing, mounting, studs, door-frame, hole-repair

I was trying to mount a shelf above the door in my bathroom. I used a stud finder before starting but apparently wasn't able to locate any studs and decided that I could use a toggle bolt I had on hand from a previous project to securely mount this shelf, I wasn't really expecting for this shelf to have anything more than towels on it, the toggle bolt was just conveniently available.

A few minutes later, I found myself drilling a 1/2" hole partially into what I think is the King stud of this door frame. I was not expecting there to be a stud, I wouldn't have used a toggle bolt for that.

What do I do now? The only idea I've come to is some type of 1/2" plug to fill the hole.

Comment: If you are worried about the integrity of the stud, don't be, in my opinion.

Comment: Please state your exact concern. @EvilElf noted that the hole in the stud isn't a worry. Is it that the hole is now oversized for a screw to mount the shelf into a stud? Also, how do you know you hit the king stud and not part of the header?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What do you do now _to accomplish what goal_? Please clarify your question. Obviously the lesson is to always start with the smaller bit. :)